# Java hibernate eclipse bin directory

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, src, bin

I am using hibernate and put xml mapping files in src/hib directory.
but when debug application eclipse run directory is bin.
Is possible to forse Eclipse also copy .xml files of mapping also to bin/hib directory? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse should do it automatically. The problem is that Hibernate, by default, loads its config file from the default package, and not from the `hib` package.

Notice that it doesn't load it by opening a file, from the current directory. It loads it as a resource from the classpath. Even if the config file ends up in a jar file, Hibernate will be able to load it, provided it is at the expected location in the package tree (i.e. at the root of the tree).